# How to add iframe tag in CMS page in Magento 2.2

Tags: cms, magento2.2.2, cms-pages, iframe

How to add iframe tag in CMS page in Magento 2.2

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" frameborder="0" width="500" height="900"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the CMS page in the admin, click the Show/Hide Editor button and paste the HTML there. The standard WYSIWYG will not render HTML.

First embed the required URL (embed.ly works). Then, copy paste into the CMS page Html render using WYSIWYG. Or, use the show/hide editor option and paste the HTML.

Comment: getting error "www.google.com refused to connect." on frontend

Comment: <html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Added the html tag in using "html" render in WYSIWYG

Comment: I get the same error in an html file outside of Magento when using the iframe code in your post. This isn't a Magento issue. Are you just trying to get an iframe to work in general and are using google as an example?

Comment: google.com using as an example

Comment: Getting this error in console X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: The console error is because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522652/refused-to-display-url-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameori/49330250. Try using a site that allows iframe usage. Youtube share is a good example.

Comment: Hi, thank you got the solution First Embed the required Url than copy paste into the CMS page Html render using WYSIWYG. I used this https://embed.ly/ website to embed